# Book on VSTO in VS2010

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

An upcoming project in my company will be to develop Excel Spreadsheets using the latest VSTO in Visual Studio 2010. Is there a good book that covers pretty much everything in relation to Excel and VSTO?
I have seen books in Amazon but not a single one specific to VSTO 4 (Visual Studio 2010).
I would like some pointers on online documentation or books to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx) at the MSDN VSTO Developer Center.  I'd look at the [Office 2010 Developer Training Courses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Office2010DeveloperTrainingCourse) link first.